# Grails Cannot get property 'id' on null object

Tags: grails

I am getting this error: Cannot get property 'id' on null object and i can't understand the problem.

Here is my code in provionController.groovy

CreateCriteria returns one element, I verified in the database, size = 1 but when i tried to display the Id, I get this error.

```
def prov_model = null
def model = Provision_model.CreateCriteria{
  gilt_air{
      eq("air",air)
  }
  gilt_coo{
      eq("coo",coo)
  }
  le("date_from", per.begin)
  ge("date_to", per.end)
  eq("active", 1)

}
println(model.size())
prov_model = model[0]
println(prov_model.id)
```

but when I am getting it directly by method get(), it hasn't no problem

```
prov_model = Provision_model.get(57)
println(prov_model.id)
```

Comment: those are some very unconventional domain class and property names. I would encourage you to follow the Groovy/Grails/Java convention of `ProvisionModel` for class names and `dateFrom` for property names

Answer (score 4):

1st: the method is called `createCriteria()`, not `CreateCriteria()`

2nd: the method itself DOES NOT invoke any db operation. You have to call `list()` or `get()` etc. on it to get the query results

Answer (score 0):

If order to execute the query and store the results in `model`, replace this

```
def model = Provision_model.CreateCriteria
```

with

```
def model = Provision_model.withCriteria
```

Comment: thank you for your answers, I modified by withCriteria but the same error still persist!

Answer (score 0):

@injecteer and @Donal both have very valid input. First, you need to address the syntax issue, here is an example of one way to format your criteria:

```
def prov_model = null
def model = Provision_model.createCriteria().get() {
    gilt_air{
      eq("air",air)
  }
  gilt_coo{
      eq("coo",coo)
  }
  le("date_from", per.begin)
  ge("date_to", per.end)
  eq("active", 1)
}
```

Keep in mind that by using `.get()` you are limiting the return from the criteria to one record. Second, if you try writing the criteria both ways, using withCriteria and using the format above and it still doesn't work, your problem may be in the domain model or the configuration of the database.